# Going back to the previous page after jquery html() function call

Tags: jquery, html

I use jquery to load a new html into an exiting page:

```
$("#app-body").html(page);
```

Since this doesn't refresh the page and doesn't change the url, the "back" button would not perform the expected action of undoing the change. Is there a simple way to simulate the desired outcome?

Comment: you have to create a routing application.but you can change url with # without refreshing the page.this is very common in single page applications .http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/deep-dive-into-client-side-routing-navigo-pushstate-hash

Comment: could you please elaborate regarding "create a routing application"? and is there a way to (instead of loading the page into the existing page) refresh and create a new page with jquery?

Comment: i amuse that you want to change the browser url .if so this is a demo application built with angular routes https://ahinea.com/en/demo/angularjs-simple-website/ .if you click the navitems you can see different pages but without refreshing the page .

Answer (score 0):

On back button click, you can simply remove HTML as below:

```
$("#app-body").html('');
```

Hope this trick can help you.